# Maven project and the files with unicode characters in the names

Tags: java, spring, maven, jenkins, unicode

I have a Maven/Spring Boot project and resource folder with a mix of files with Latin and non Latin characters.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
        <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>false</addResources>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -Xdebug
                        -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>true</useDefaultDelimiters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Right now on the Linux machine after the Maven build(on Jenkins) the resource folder inside of the generated war file contains only the files with a names with Latin characters only.. all files with a filenames with non Latin characters are absent there.

What am I doing wrong and how to tell Maven to place all files there ? By the way - on the Windows machine everything is working fine

**UPDATED**

Also, I have updated my Jenkins and now have all of the files in my war file. But right now I have another issue - all non-Latin characters in file names after unzipping(war file) look like `??????`

Looks like Jenkins/Maven build kills the files names for a some reason. How to fix it ?

This is a sample war file with Unicode file name inside: [war file](http://www.thedownloadplanet.com/files/api.war) that after unzipping on the Linux machine looks like `??????`

Comment: Did you try to define `<project.build.sourceEncoding>utf-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>` in the `<properties>` section?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy yes, it didn't help

Comment: I noticed one thing - I have executed the Maven build directly from CLI.. all of the files are present.. but why these files are absent after the Jenkins build.. How Jenkins can impact on this process ?

Comment: What is the file system on your Jenkins (Linux) box? Can you create manually any file there with non-Latin characters in its name?

Comment: Yes, I can create non-Latin characters. Also, I have updated my Jenkins and now have all of the files in my war file. But right now I have another issue - all non-Latin characters in file names after unzipping(war file) look like `??????` Looks like Jenkins/Maven build kills the files names for a some reason.

Comment: The problem is with the file/folder names or content? If it is the names, sorry you will have to change then all. If it is with their content you have to save then as UTF-8 files. My guess here is that the files are saved with non UTF-8 enconding and when the jenkins checkout the project to build it cames as is in a linux system it will be encoded to the question marks. Been there done that.

Comment: The file content is UTF8. The problem is with the file names only. Why should I change it ?

Answer (score 0):

the following changes to `pom.xml` helped me:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
                <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -ea -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below properties inside your `pom.xml` file

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```